# How to solve matrix differential equations in Python?

Tags: python, controls, linear-algebra, ode

`dx/dt = Ax` where `A`, `x` belongs to `n x n` array. 
I have tried using `solve_ivp` and `odeint` features in `scipy.integrate`, but both these work only with `n x 1` arrays.

Comment: Can you integrate over all n? so have a nested loop of integration? i.e. break down x into n (nx1) arrays)

Comment: Yes. This can be done. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrators expect that the ODE function consumes a flat, one-dimensional array as the state variable and returns an equally flat derivatives vector. This input array contains the entries of the matrix. To perform matrix operations on it, you need to build a matrix from the flat input array, and in the end reverse that for the output of the derivatives function

```
x0 = x0.reshape(-1);         # make data 1-dimensional
def odefun(t,x):
    x=x.reshape([n,n]);      # restore to matrix form
    dx=A.dot(x);             # perform matrix operations
    return dx.reshape(-1);   # return 1-dimensional vector

sol = solve_ivp(odefun, [t0, tf], x0)
```